# Can't access internet through Google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I can't access internet through my chrome browser,but can access net through all other browsers in the same system. Tried uninstalling and installing chrome but of no use...Is there any solution for this ?

[image]

this is the issue....

Comment: This requires a lot more information. What process did you use to uninstall? What OS are you using? Have you restarted your PC and ran a chkdsk if windows for example.

Comment: I just unistalled it through control panel, and I am using windows 8.1 os

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already uninstalled it let's start here:

**Step 1**: Enable the Hidden Files View.

- To do that go to:
- Start > Control Panel > Folder Options.
- Click the View tab.
- Click/Check the Show hidden files, folders, and drives option.
- Uncheck the Hide protected operating system files option.
- Press  OK.

**Step 2**: Delete any Chrome or Google folders from your computer.
Navigate to the following locations and delete the Chrome folder(s). You can also choose to rename them. I would also search you computer for any google or chrome folder to make sure.

```
C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome

C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome
```

**Step 3**: Schedule a check disk
To do this use:

`chkdsk c: /r`

where 'c' is the drive with chrome installed. You can add other drives as well just in case you had multiple installations. To do this basically replace c with the drive letter.

**Step 5**: Reboot PC and reinstall chrome.

**Optional Step**: if the above still fails. Download CCleaner. Restart in safe mode with networking. Repeat the above steps but run CCleaner as the final step.

Comment: sorry its not working... i have added the screenshot with the question..

Comment: haha you said it was working. can you access the internet from any other browser? If yes then reset chrome settings and let me know what happens. Relevant link: https://www.howtogeek.com/171924/how-to-reset-your-web-browser-to-its-default-settings/

Also it could be your proxy settings. Try and rest them as well. Relevant link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_web/windows-10-build-9879-proxy-server-settings/d7bbc6dd-5539-4e68-93c1-9401468701b5?auth=1

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is check if there is a proxy turned on system-wide or even in chrome, turn it off. type that "chrome://settings" in your URL bar of chrome: and search for proxy

Comment: If system-wide, then the other browsers wouldn't work. If in Chrome, then the setting would go away after a reinstall.